# change parents div height on childs element height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have div page and inside that div I have bootstrap multiselect container

```
<div class="content clearfix">
   <ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu">
       <li> ...</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

problem is that when there are many list items inside this multiselect element it stays hidden under parent div. How can I dynamically change parent div height as multiselection container element height change?

I tried already with

```
.content.clearfix {
    height:auto;
}
```

but that doesn't helped

Comment: Can you make a demo?

Comment: try `.content.clearfix {
    height:auto;
overflow: hidden;
}`

Comment: @Tamil, nope, still same

Comment: try `height: 100%;` instead of `height:auto;`

Comment: try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/12c963er/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try JS to set height dynamically as per your multi-list element height. Check if it can help to you. I just put this code inside setTimeout because in case your li elements are taking time to load on page. Please try without setTimeout function first.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
setTimeout(function(){
var multiselectHeight=$('.multiselect-container').height();
  $('.content').height(multiselectHeight);
  
},1000);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content clearfix">
   <ul class="multiselect-container dropdown-menu">
       <li> ...</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```